# Simplifying radicals

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

I am stuck in the following puzzle and couldn't find a way to approach this.

$\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{14 + \sqrt{180}}}}$

Please help.

Comment: Write $\sqrt{180} = a\sqrt{5}$, see that $14+\sqrt{180}$ is a square, continue in the same manner for the result in the next outer square root until you reach the end.

Comment: It evaluates to $\sqrt{5} + 1$.

Answer (score 7):

$$
\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{14 + \sqrt{180}}}} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+3)^2}}} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{5} + 3}} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{5}+1)^2}} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{5}+1}=\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5}+1
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\eqalign{
  & \sqrt{14 + \sqrt {180}}  = 3 + \sqrt 5   \cr 
  & \sqrt {3 + \sqrt 5  + 3 + \sqrt 5 }  = \sqrt {6 + 2\sqrt 5 }  = 1 + \sqrt 5   \cr 
  & \sqrt {5 + \sqrt 5  + \sqrt {3 + \sqrt 5  + 3 + \sqrt 5 } }  = \sqrt {6 + 2\sqrt 5 }  = 1 + \sqrt 5  \cr} $$